# in angular i have data of movies. using route parameters when i go to some movie page, video tag doesn't work and i get some error

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components, html5-video

i have movies json file, in which i have info (title, year , movieUrl and so on). when i create video tag and put any movie url in this tag url it works. but i want this video tag in movie component, where using route.param id i get that movie info on which i click in movies component

so when i use video tag in movies component

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
    <video>
        <source src="{{movie.movieUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

it works

when i create it in movie component

```
<div>
    <video controls>
        <source src="{{movies[movieId].movieUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

it doesn't.

movieId comes from here:

```
 movieId:any;

  constructor(private mainService:MainService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => { this.movieId = params['id']; });
  }
```

error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: Movies seems to be an array (because you’re looping through it) so this looks incorrect: movies[movieId]

Comment: About `this.movieId = params['id'];` what data type is **params**? Use `console.log( "datatype params is: " + params);`. If it really is an `Array` then it expects a numerical position for your required item inside the array (starting at **0**), and since `'id'` is text not a number, it will error. **(1)** Do you know which array's slot hold the "id" item?  **(2)**  It is also possible that **params** is really a JSON `Object` and so you must actually read the **id** as `this.movieId = params.id;`. **(3)** If still struggling then just show some example JSON and code to reproduce your problem.